# jQuery next table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't figure out why 'table' with AAA is not selected:

```
<b>CLICK ME!</b>
<br/>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>AAA</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<b>CLICK ME!</b>
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>BBB</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', "b", function(){
      $(this).next("table").css('background-color', 'red');
    });
  });
</script>
```

When using `$(this).next().next().css('background-color', 'red');`  the table is found.

**NOT looking for nextAll, I only need the first table after clicked element.**

Comment: "Not working" is never a valid question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) searches the very next sibling element which in this case is the `<br/>` not the table., what you might be looking for is [`.nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and to get the first table in the selection you can use [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/) or jQuery's [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector

```
$(this).nextAll("table").eq(0).css('background-color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xcNhN/

```
$(this).nextAll("table:first").css('background-color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xcNhN/1/

Answer (score 1):

Sorted with:

```
$(this).nextAll("table:first")
```

Comment: You don't need to post an answer with what you actually used, when Musa already has. If you used their suggestion, accept the answer. If you tweaked the code, comment on their answer explaining. If you need more help, comment on their answer.

Comment: @Ian this is not actually the same as Musa's answer. Musa's solution did not have `:first`, and would have wrongly included extra tables. If the purpose is to have a long-term reference of useful questions, it makes sense to have this as an actual answer, rather than a comment.

Comment: @jcsanyi It doesn't matter if it's the exact same or not. Musa provided a solution to the original problem - `next` was incorrect, `nextAll` was needed. The OP then went on to edit their question and change the requirement. Instead of doing that, they should've explained better in the first place, or commented on Musa's answer for more help. Musa could've easily provided a fix. There's rarely a reason for the OP to add an answer. And your answer just duplicates Musa's and this answer, so it's really not needed

Comment: @Ian It comes down to whether you view the purpose of answering and accepting as rewarding the answerer - and the first answerer has a certain 'claim' to the points that they're cheated out of if somebody else posts - or if you view it as building a high-quality set of questions and answers and the points will sort themselves out. I didn't immediately realize that this answer was from the OP, and I was trying to provide a more useful answer that explained some of the reasons instead of just giving a copy/paste solution.

Comment: @jcsanyi You're right, that's a good way to look at it. Your answer is valid, and has a lot good info, so I'll upvote it :) As for this OP's answer, I still think it was unnecessary - they could've gotten help from Musa or told Musa what they ended up using, because they were the one that got them that far...or accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.next()` will only look at the immediately following element. If you include a selector, it'll check whether that element matches, and if it doesn't, it'll just return an empty set.

To do what you're trying to do, you need to use `.nextAll()` instead.

I understand that you only want the first table, while `.nextAll()` will return all subsequent tables. To fix that, you can either explicitly include `:first` in your selector, like this:

```
$(this).nextAll('table:first')
```

...or you can trim the list down once you get all of them:

```
$(this).nextAll('table').eq(0)
```

You can see an example of this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/6x3EY/

Comment: To make it even more better/complete, you could add a jsFiddle or something :)